# Kinetic JS - scaling handles for shape not behaving predictably

Tags: kineticjs

I have tried to adopt the code found on the HTML5 Kinetic Canvas Tutorial called "http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/".

For some reason I cannot convert the tutorial (which scales images) to scale a blob.
At least, not in a predictable manner. The area of code that is the problem (I think) is this:

```
    //shape.setPosition(topLeft.getPosition());

    var width = topRight.x() - topLeft.x();
    var height = bottomLeft.y() - topLeft.y();

    var w = group.width0;
    var h = group.height0;

    var scaleX = width / w;
    var scaleY = height / h;

    if( width && height ) {

        shape.scale({x: scaleX, y: scaleY});
        shape.setPosition( { x: - topLeft.x(), y: - topLeft.y() } );

    }
```

Working Demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/JSdc2/6WUTy/13/

Does anyone know why this isn't working.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out - I was recording Screen coordinates, and populating the new spline with them directly. To fix it, I 'zeroed' out the array, so the new shape data is at 0,0. Works fine now.   http://jsfiddle.net/JSdc2/6WUTy/16/

Comment: In other words, if your mouse is in the middle of the user's screen, and recording points, those points are in the 'middle' of the screen, wheras for a kinetic shape, you need them to be starting at  0,0. So what you do is search through the coordinates you recorded, and find the smallest number, and subtract that from all the coordinates (respecting x, and y). Then, your kinetic shape will be at 0,0 and will work predictably.